# Weird artifact when offseting linestring within polygon

Tags: geopandas, shapely, offset

I have a code that, starting with a main line that crosses a polygon, creates a sequence of parallel lines by offsetting the main line to both directions and then clipping the parallels with the polygon borders. However, once in a while (not always) it creates an artifact as below.

This is the main line crossing the polygon
[image: This is the main line crossing the polygon]

this it the artifact after offsetting but before clipping
[image: this it the artifact after offsetting but before clipping]

The code is below:

```
def createGDPwithMultipleParallelLines(polygon, line_geoseries, \
                                        offset, crs, direction):
    '''
    creating empty gp_df to append new parallel lines
    '''
    n=0
    gp_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=['id', 'geometry'], crs = crs)
    newParallelLinestring = line_geoseries['geometry'][0]
    gp_df, n = appendLineToGDF(gp_df, crs, newParallelLinestring, n)
    newOffset = offset
    newParallelLinestring \
        = line_geoseries['geometry'][0].parallel_offset(newOffset, direction, \
                                                        join_style=2)
    while (newParallelLinestring.crosses(polygon)) is True:
        gp_df, n = appendLineToGDF(gp_df, crs, newParallelLinestring, n)
        newOffset = newOffset + offset
        newParallelLinestring \
            = line_geoseries['geometry'][0].parallel_offset(newOffset, \
                                                            direction, join_style=2)
        gp_df, n = appendLineToGDF(gp_df, crs, newParallelLinestring, n)

    newOffset = -1*offset
    newParallelLinestring \
        = line_geoseries['geometry'][0].parallel_offset(newOffset, \
                                                        direction, join_style=2)
    gp_df, n = appendLineToGDF(gp_df, crs, newParallelLinestring, n)
    newOffset = newOffset - offset
    newParallelLinestring \
        = line_geoseries['geometry'][0].parallel_offset(newOffset, \
                                                        direction, join_style=2)
    while (newParallelLinestring.crosses(polygon)) is True:
        gp_df, n = appendLineToGDF(gp_df, crs, newParallelLinestring, n)        
        newOffset = newOffset - offset
        newParallelLinestring \
            = line_geoseries['geometry'][0].parallel_offset(newOffset, \
                                                          direction, join_style=2)
        gp_df, n = appendLineToGDF(gp_df, crs, newParallelLinestring, n)
    return gp_df

def appendLineToGDF(gp_df, crs, line, n):
    '''
    append line to geopandas dataframe
    '''
    seg = {'id':n,'geometry': [line]}
    gp_df_offset = gpd.GeoDataFrame(seg, crs=crs)
    gp_df = gp_df.append(gp_df_offset)
    n+=1
    return gp_df, n
```

I wonder whether there is a problem with my code, there are some unique conditions that create these artifacts, or it is something related to shapely itself.

More details: I tested line by line until the problem appears. The artifact begins when offset line no longer shows a corner on the left side. It seems that shapely generates a bad solution when that happens.

[image]

Comment: This looks the correct result to me. Can you include an illustration of the expected output? At some stage the order of vertices is going to cause a self-intersection when doing this operation on curves, if the original order is retained. An alternative approach could be to translate your original geometry; this would be a simpler computation too.

Comment: Sorry, Can you explain what you mean  by translating the geometry? Can we predict when and where this will happen? It looks quite arbitrary to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry) (But I don't actually understand what you're trying to do here, it just resembles translation to me.) You can achieve it in shapely with [`shapely.affinity.translate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.affinity.translate)

Comment: I want to create parallel lines starting of the main line. Offsetting seemed to be the way to go. I am not sure the translation documented above will do this, but will explore the possibility.